# Browse button to look for files from a specified location - cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an `ASP.NET MVC` application.
I have a text box in my cshtml and I store some path in it.

```
eg: \\abc\def\hig\lmn
```

And I have a button of type="file" beside it.
When I click on the button, the dialog to choose the files from should point to the path in textBox instead of open my local hard drive folders.

My cshtml looks like this

```
<div class="row">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Link, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Link, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="file" id='inputFile' />

                </div>
 </div>
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: You can't control the contents of a file input for security reasons. And not sure what you mean by _instead of open my local hard drive folders_ - the use can only ever select files on their computer/network

Comment: What I meant is, Input button will always open a dialog to browse from local hard drive/network. What I need is, when I click on the button, it should take the path from textbox and browse from the location specified in the text box.

Comment: What if one of your user does not have access to that location ?  Why are you doing this ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: You cannot for security reasons (and what is the point anyway - the user can just navigate the the directory in the dialog)